# Допуск к эксплуатации или допуск в эксплуатацию?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

Какой предлог правильно использовать?
*Допуск **к** эксплуатации* или *допуск **в** эксплуатацию.*

Answer (score 2):

Допуск **к** эксплуатации, либо допуск **к** *введению **в** эксплуатацию*.